# How to determine minimum aluminum t-slot profile type for frame?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, aluminum, machine-design

For a frame with dimensions 1000x1000x400, I am determining which T-slot extrusion type will be strong enough.

I am considering both 30-6060 (30 series I-type, metric) and 20-4040 (20 series I-type, metric).

The extrusions will be joined by fairly small corner brackets, which will only be mounted on the inner T-slot of each extrusion. On the outer T-slot, I will be inserting a polymer panel using a rubber seal/profile to ensure the panel seals properly.

For simplicity's sake I am not planning to add anny additional structural supports, ideally the extrusions themselves should be strong enough.

Whether the frame is sturdy enough depends of course entirely on the requirements. I will be using this frame to mount a sliding mechanism, sort of like a drawer, except it will be motorized. The total weight of the "drawer" (the moving part of the drawer + anything mounted on it) will be around 5-6KG. Apart from this drawer mechanism, not much else will be mounted into the frame.
I am planning the add two additional horizontal extrusions, mounted with the same brackets. On to these extrusions I will be mounting the linear guides for the "drawer" mechanism.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

[image: Cross section of 2020 20-series extrusion]
[image: Cross section of 6060 30-series extrusion]
[image: Visualisation comparing the two frames]
[image: Corner bracket when using the 30 series extrusion system e]